# Error returning an object attribute in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

```
function Objecte(name){

    this.name=name;

}

Objecte.prototype.look=function(){

    return function(){

        alert(this.name);

    };

}
```

I'm trying to access the Object's attribute but when I call the function, it alerts undefined.

```
extintor = new Objecte("extintor");

$(document).on('dblclick',"#extintor",extintor.look());
```

Comment: wrapping it and returning a function doesn't change the fact that jQuery will use `.call(this,event)` on it, resulting in `this` referencing the clicked element and not your `this`.

Comment: You wrote Objecte and not Object

Comment: [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) has meaning in JavaScript!

Comment: The actual name of the Object is Objecte, that's not it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not lexically defined. You need to capture its value in order to ensure that the returned function can use it.

```
Objecte.prototype.look=function(){
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        alert(self.name);
    };
}
```

---

You can also use `$.proxy`

```
Objecte.prototype.look=function(){
    return $.proxy(function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }, this);
}
```

---

or `.bind()` in modern browsers

```
Objecte.prototype.look=function(){
    return function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function that you return has another context of `this`.

Therefore you have two options:

**1. Create a reference to `this` outside and use it inside your anonymous function**

```
Objecte.prototype.look = function() {
    var objecteInstance = this;
    return function() {
        alert(objecteInstance.name);
    };
}
```

**2. Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which is supported in all major browsers including IE9+**

```
Objecte.prototype.look = function() {
    return function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

If you don't need to support IE8 and lower, then the second option it is - as for me it looks more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Does look need to return a function? I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
Objecte.prototype.look=function(){

    alert(this.name);

}
```

However, `this` in this context will be resolved when the function is executed and could be bound to another object. I think it is clearer in any case to use the closure declaration of objects instead of using the prototype. You could declare your object this way:

```
function Objecte(name) {
    var that = this;

    this.name = name;

    this.look = function() {
        alert(that.name);
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is that every object of the type Objecte will have its own copy of the function look, but when was the last time you ran out of memory?
Another disadvantage is that you can't inherit from another object, rewrite a method and later call the original method from this object, as it will be lost. However disadvantageous that is..